# c#, закрыть окно

Tags: c#, окно, процесс

Необходимо послать сигнал завершения окну. Именно сигнал завершения, убить процесс не пойдёт - их несколько, да и окон работает работает сразу 2-3, процессы не те закрываются.

Comment: Своему окну или чужому?

Comment: Чужое окно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При условии, что у вас есть хэндл окна, которое вы пытаетесь закрыть, посылка WM_CLOSE сработает

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr handle, UInt32 message, IntPtr w, IntPtr l);

static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

public void CloseWindow(IntPtr handle)
{
    SendMessage(handle, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Конкретное окно внутри приложения в WPF закрывается так:

```
foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows ) {
    if (window.Name = "...") {
        window.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Application.Current.Windows"
Application не существует в текущем контексте, нажал "разрешить", в вариантах только "System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application", и то не подходит.

Comment: Так, приложение не WPF, консольное. Может, альтернативы?

Answer (score -2):

Чет такого наговорил, мосх ломаешь?))

```
setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Я попросил закрыть окно, а не делать его невидимым. Окно - батник, запускающий java-приложение, необходимо послать сигнал завершения.

Comment: Как это должно помочь?